# CS50 bottoms up, BMP file Concept

Tags: c, cs50

The problem was to turn the BMP image 180 degrees, To do this I am aware that that I must change the value of biHeight to the opposite sign as the input image's biheight. But I am unable to figure out how to do so. Could Somebody please help me understand how I can perform this task.

I have tried this:

bi.biHeight = (abs(bi.biHeight));

```
// Copies a BMP file, this is the distribution code I have to work on.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "bmp.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Ensure proper usage
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: copy infile outfile\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Remember filenames
    char *infile = argv[1];
    char *outfile = argv[2];

    // Open input file
    FILE *inptr = fopen(infile, "r");
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open %s.\n", infile);
        return 2;
    }

    // Open output file
    FILE *outptr = fopen(outfile, "w");
    if (outptr == NULL)
    {
        fclose(inptr);
        printf("Could not create %s.\n", outfile);
        return 3;
    }

    // Read infile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bf;
    fread(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, inptr);

    // Read infile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bi;
    fread(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, inptr);

    // Ensure infile is (likely) a 24-bit uncompressed BMP 4.0
    if (bf.bfType != 0x4d42 || bf.bfOffBits != 54 || bi.biSize != 40 ||
        bi.biBitCount != 24 || bi.biCompression != 0)
    {
        fclose(outptr);
        fclose(inptr);
        printf("Unsupported file format.\n");
        return 4;
    }

    // Write outfile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
    fwrite(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, outptr);

    // Write outfile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
    fwrite(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, outptr);

    // Determine padding for scanlines
    int padding = (4 - (bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;


    // Iterate over infile's scanlines
    for (int i = 0, biHeight = (abs(bi.biHeight)); i < biHeight; i++)
    {
        // Iterate over pixels in scanline
        for (int j = 0; j < bi.biWidth; j++)
        {
            // Temporary storage
            RGBTRIPLE triple;

            // Read RGB triple from infile
            fread(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, inptr);

            // Write RGB triple to outfile
            fwrite(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, outptr);
        }

        // Skip over padding, if any
        fseek(inptr, padding, SEEK_CUR);

        // Then add it back (to demonstrate how)
        for (int k = 0; k < padding; k++)
        {
            fputc(0x00, outptr);
        }
    }

    // Close infile
    fclose(inptr);

    // Close outfile
    fclose(outptr);

    // Success
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Converting the vertical direction of bitmap won't turn it by 180 degrees. It will flip it instead of turning it (so the image is reversed). Anyway, you would need not `bi.biHeight = abs(bi.biHeight);` but `bi.biHeight = -bi.biHeight;`.

Comment: Aside: `fopen()` and `fclose()` are pretty self-explanatory, you don't need to document their purpose. And instead of returning arbitrary numbers, consider using `EXIT_SUCCESS`, and `EXIT_FAILURE`. And you should check if `fread` and `fwrite` succeeded.

Comment: If the format also allowed the width to be negative, you could just negate the height and the width, and job done! Unfortunately, that does not work because the width MUST be positive.

Comment: Open files in _binary_.  Example: `fopen(infile, "r");` --> `fopen(infile, "rb");`

Comment: 180 degrees... Okay... Around which axis???